# Center Text Vertically, exactly

Tags: vertical-spacing

I tried two of the solutions given on this forum.  Neither of them really center the text.  I put one below.  It's off by quite a bit.  I'd like it centered measuring from the textblock(?...the rectangle where the normal text is written) to the middle of the letter height (the capital letter is fine).

```
%\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book} % A4 paper size, default 11pt font size and oneside for equal margins

%PACKAGES
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, showframe]{geometry}

\fancypagestyle{clearstyle}{\fancyhead{}\fancyfoot{}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
{\Huge \textbf{\textit{Too Low}}\par}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\end{center}

\clearpage 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will there be anything else on the first page? You could consider using [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic).

Comment: I have one page kind of like this with just one or two large words.  Then I have another with a poem quote+author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use this (albeit, in my opinion, the golden ratio would be finer).:

```
\begin{center}
\null\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
{\Huge \textbf{\textit{Too Low}}\par}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}\null
\end{center}

\clearpage
```

[image]

Here is a code with values for `stretch` approximating the golden ratio (for the text area):

```
\begin{center}
\null\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
{\Huge \textbf{\textit{Too Low}}\par}
\vspace*{\stretch{1.72}\null
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean 'golden ratio'?  How would that look?

Comment: The ratio `\belowspace/abovespace` is equal to (1+squareroot(5))/2 (~1.618).

Comment: Is there a way to modify the example you gave, so I can compare?

Comment: Do you mean, to approximate the golden ratio?

Comment: Ya, I just wanted to see how that would look on the page.  I like the solution you gave.  It does what I wanted.

Comment: Please my addition (it worked with trial and error, to compesate for the text height).

Comment: I don't hate it, but I like 1:1 better.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's only a matter of appreciation.

Comment: @Bernard very interesting -- https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/golden-ratio.html  -- read it in abook I think by John Grisham --human body arms are in the same ratio upper arm to lower arm and petals of a fllower

Answer (score 2):

You may use [textpos](https://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) to place your text absolutely in the middle of a grid- However, when the text is centred in the middle of the page, it will optically look as too low.

I have not compensated for the height of the textbox, so probably, the text should place approximately 2 mm higher.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\TPGrid[-7mm,0mm]{210}{290}

\begin{document}
\begin{textblock}{54}(78,145)
{\Huge \textbf{\textit{Too Low gg}}\par}
\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below I use [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic)'s `\AtTextCenter` to place an object at the centre of the text block. Since the object is text, which is placed on the baseline, dropping (or raising it with a negative distance) it exactly halfway helps to centre it vertically on the page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

%PACKAGES
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\mbox{}% Just to put something on the page
\AddToShipoutPicture*{%
  \AtTextCenter{%
    \makebox[0pt]{\raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height+.5\depth}{\fbox{\Huge\bfseries Lazy fox}}}%
  }%
}

%\clearpage% Ship out page

\end{document}
```

You can, of course, remove the `\fbox` and other elements that don't fit with your usage.